# cxgrid's memo field keeps inserting new line

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

In cxGrid I have a field with properties of a memo. The field column `Properties.EditAutoHeight` is set to `ieahDefault`.

The view `DBTableView1` has following:

- `OptionsView.CellAutoHeight = True`
- `OptionsBehavior.EditAutoHeight=eahRow`

However when I try and add some text to
data already in that field (directly editing in the grid), the edited line jumps one line down as if I am going to enter the new text in a new line.It behaves just like as if I pressed enter to go down to new line.

Is there a setting in the grid that prevents this 'new line' behavior when I try and edit the record?

Comment: I understand this happens to you when editing an existing row. Anyway, I have tried to reproduce it both when inserting and editing and could not (with version 13.2.3 of `tcxGrid`). I suspect there is some other code affecting the value that you have not mentioned.

Comment: No other code...Did you try in the second or third row?

Comment: Yes, did so. No difference there. Maybe some other property you have set?